# Replace Bones with existing bones from other models | 1 animation for 2 differnt models

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, pose-mode

i think there is a easy way to fix but i cant find it(Beginner).
So i have two different models; 1 Character and 1 weapon both of them have their own pose/bones but I can see that the bones/pose from the weapon are similar too the bones from the character. Now i want to use an  animation of both together but it will only apply to one of the models, not both. How can I fix it?[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the armature that doesn't have the animation, create a dope sheet window, turn it to an action editor, select your animation in the drop down menu.

[image]